# Can we combine server-side pagination and client-side filtering in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I need to use server-side pagination along with client-side filtering. Wanted to know if we have any option for that using rowModelType.

I tried setting rowModelType as 'serverSide' and 'clientSide' in the places wherever applicable.But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not feasible to use server-side pagination and client-side filtering at the same time.

Frankly, I'm not sure how that would work, and if you did, you'd wind up with very high chances for encountering 'edge' conditions, like your filter filtering out all of the rows in a page returned by the server, resulting in no rows showing in the grid.

My suggestion is to do one or the other.
If you have too many rows to be able to hold them all in memory on the client side, then you'd have to do the extra work necessary to do server-side filtering along with the server-side pagination.